# What is the difference between java *.java and java *.class

Tags: java

Hello Here is very simple code and I'm curious about the difference between 'java Main.java and Main.class

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

when I compile the Main.java source it creates the Main.class and then I know the proccess of the JVM Work but I just got to know That I can execute Main source without compiling

and it takes a little bit more time when I execute java Main.java

so why it doesn't create Main.class when I execute `java Main.java` and how it is possible to execute without creating Main.class file?

I expected no Result and error occurs but not..

Comment: You are using the Java "script"/"interpreter" mode available since Java 11.

Comment: `*.java` is the source file and `*.class` is the file that the JVM runs.  I don't understand the rest of your statements.  You can't execute a source file.  It always has to be compiled into a class file.  It may happen dynamically under the covers of an IDE, but it has to happen.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc since Java 11 you can start simple java programs using the so called source mode (https://openjdk.org/jeps/330, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE) with `java source.java`

Comment: @ThomasKläger: The Java script/interpreter creates class code under the covers.  Okay, it doesn't create a class "file".

Answer (score 0):

The `.java` files are source files, whereas `.class` files are the bytecode generated by `javac` - the Java Compiler.

By doing

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

The compiler generates the bytecode.

In general, you do not run the `.java` files without compiling it. If you're running the project from a IDE, the IDE is *probably* compiling your code and then executing it. It's a two-step process where the code gets compiled and then executed. You do not see the `.class` compiled files if they were generated by the IDE, because they're *typically* located in a temporary hidden directory and not in the project directory.